# How to remove child attribute when parent class is active

Tags: attributes, href, children

```
 if($("ul.multicb > li").hasClass('active')) {
     $(this).children().removeAttr("href");
 }
```

I want to remove the href attribute from the anchor links that are children of li that contain the class .active, but my code here doesn't seem to work. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
if($("ul.multicb > li").hasClass('active')) {
 $(this).find('a').each(function(){
   $(this).removeAttr("href");
})
}
```

Comment: Hmmm unfortunately it hasn't worked for me. It does work when I put this

if($("ul.multicb > li").hasClass('active')) {
 $("ul.multicb > li > a").removeAttr("href");
}

but then it just removes the hrefs from all the list items and I just want it to remove from the list item with the active class

Comment: `if($("ul.multicb > li").hasClass('active')) {


    $("ul.multicb > li > a").removeAttr("href");


}`

Comment: Sorry I'm having a hard time formatting the code :/

Comment: Sorry. I did'nt get the exact html structure here. Is there a single anchor tag for each <li> or are there multiple anchor tags nested in each li? It will be helpful if you give the html structure. Thanks